# How to query an EF model (EDMX document) with XPath

Tags: xml, entity-framework, xpath

I'm trying to write a utility that automatically sets the `ProviderManifestToken` attribute in an EDMX document Schema element, but even my basic XPath is not working.  What am I doing wrong?

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema Namespace="PvmmsModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2005
```

My attempt:

```
        var edmx = new XmlDocument();            
        edmx.Load(@"C:\Development\Provantage\PvmmsApp\Model.edmx");
        var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(edmx.NameTable);
        nsm.AddNamespace("edmx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx");

        var x = edmx.SelectSingleNode("//edmx:Edmx/edmx:Runtime/edmx:StorageModels", nsm);
```

This works, but as soon as I append `Schema` to the query.  Then I get a null result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how a complete `Schema` element actually looks (your snippet seems to be trimmed);

```
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl"
        Namespace="Model1.Store"
        Alias="Self"
        Provider="System.Data.SqlClient"
        ProviderManifestToken="2005">
```

Note the `xmlns` part. So it's actually in a namespace, despite the lack of prefix.

Now, in XPath, the lack of prefix *always* means "not in any namespace". So you'll need to bind some prefix specifically for your XPath, and use that in the query:

```
...
nsm.AddNamespace("ssdl", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl");
var x = edmx.SelectSingleNode(
    "//edmx:Edmx/edmx:Runtime/edmx:StorageModels/ssdl:Schema", nsm)
```

Comment: Thanks for solving my problem, and +1 for the new XPath knowledge.